# Code Style enforcement tool (Bitbucket Cloud would be nice)

Tags: git, code-analysis, code-review

I work in a team of 5 developers. We would like to enforce a code style from now on. However we cannot find a suitable Bitbucket Cloud integrations. If we had Bitbucket Server [Code Review Assistant](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/ch.mibex.stash.cra/server/overview) would be an excellent choice.

We use PHPStorm and its Code Style, however we cannot easily see if a Pull Request follows the PSR-2 style without checking it out and analyzing every file by hand. Besides older code is not yet expected to follow the style (we're talking about a 10+ year old project). Any suggestions how to do this? I was thinking about maybe some git hook or Bitbucket pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this tool : https://github.com/phpro/grumphp which is pretty cool. It works as a composer package and uses git hook.

Answer (score 0):

I use phpcodesniffer, phpcs.

There is a Visual Studio Code Editor [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ikappas.phpcs) available for it.

See there for installation of the extension and the tool itself.

The finetuning of the linter configuration can be very awkward though. But it does auto-format on save and enforce PSR-2 style when the Visual Studio COde project is open.